# How to change font size in plottable js bar chart?

Tags: javascript, svg

I m new to javascript, i am using plottable js to draw bar graph, bar graph is fine but the font size of x-axis label is large, can anyone help me how to reduce font size? Here is my html and javascript code.

snapshot: 
[image]

HTML code:

```
<svg height="200px" width="400px" style="margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; display:block;" id="Individual-assessment-score-graph">
</svg>
```

js Code:

```
<script>
        var data = [
            <% for(var i=0; i < studentData.pageInclination.assessmentScoreChart.length; i++) {%>
                { 
                    testScore: <%= studentData.pageInclination.assessmentScoreChart[i].testScore %>,
                    barColor: <%= studentData.pageInclination.assessmentScoreChart[i].barColor %>,
                    chartLegend: "<%= studentData.pageInclination.assessmentScoreChart[i].chartLegend %>"
                 },
            <%}%>
            ];
        var colors = [
        <% for(var i=0; i < studentData.pageInclination.chartBarColors.length; i++) {%>
                "<%= studentData.pageInclination.chartBarColors[i] %>",
            <%}%>
        ];


        var colorScale = new Plottable.Scales.Color();
            colorScale.range(colors);

        var dataSet = new Plottable.Dataset(data);
        var xAccessor = function(datum, index, dataset) {
            return datum.chartLegend;
            };            
        var xScale = new Plottable.Scales.Category(); 


        var yScale = new Plottable.Scales.Linear();
        var yAccessor = function(datum, index, dataset) {
            return datum.testScore;
        };

        var plot = new Plottable.Plots.Bar();
        plot.addDataset(dataSet);
        plot.x(xAccessor, xScale);
        var xAxis = new Plottable.Axes.Category(xScale, "bottom");
        var yAxis = new Plottable.Axes.Numeric(yScale, "left");
        var chart = new Plottable.Components.Table([
            [yAxis, plot],
            [null, xAxis]
        ]);

        chart.renderTo("svg#Individual-assessment-score-graph");
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To Change the font size of your X-Axis label, You can either edit the `.plottable .axis text` classe's `font-size` attribute in your `plottable.css` file, (Or) you can add even add the same class to your own css file to override the existing size.

The `.plottable .axis text` class will look like this (in your `plottable.css` file,

```
.plottable .axis text {
  fill: #32313F;
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px; // => Change this value according to your need
  font-weight: 200;
  line-height: normal;
}
```

Hope this helps!